# How do I add elements to an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

What I'm trying to do is find a way to add extra elements to the already hardcoded int array matrix. Here is my current code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int matrix[25] = {2,3};
    int i;
    int j;

    for(i=4,j=2; i<21 && j<17; i++,j++){
        matrix[j] = i;
    }
    printf("%d", matrix);
}
```

I'm not sure what went wrong here.

Comment: Can you say specifically what output you are getting and compare that to the output that you expect to get? An obvious point is that `printf("%d", matrix)` will print out an integer, not the whole matrix.

Comment: Your compiler doesn't give you a warning about that printf? Turn up warning options till it does (use `-Wall -Wextra` for gcc and clang).

Comment: `matrix[25] = {2,3};` initializes the 25 element array with 2,3,0,0,0....  In C, once an   array is defined, its size _cannot_ change.

Answer (score 1):

You can't print array elements with integer type specifier `%d`. You need to iterate through the array elements using a loop such as `for` and then print each element.

```
for(int x=0; x < 17; x++) {
   printf("%d", matrix[x]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving to print directly matrix but it will show a warning like this

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
```

this is because when you give only matrix without indexes([]) or '*' it prints garbage value so you can use loops for printing a matrix

```
for(int i=0; i < 17; i++)
   printf("%d", matrix[i]);
```

OR

```
for(int i=0; i < 17; i++) 
   printf("%d ", *(matrix+i));
```

Peace!

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
    int main() 
{ 
    int r = 3, c = 4; 
    int *arr = (int *)malloc(r * c * sizeof(int)); 

    int i, j, count = 0; 
    for (i = 0; i <  r; i++) *emphasized text*
      for (j = 0; j < c; j++) 
         *(arr + i*c + j) = ++count; 

    for (i = 0; i <  r; i++) 
      for (j = 0; j < c; j++) 
         printf("%d ", *(arr + i*c + j));
```

Use can use malloc to to create dynamic array. by using the malloc if the size of the array is full you can reallocate the array by using the malloc function. The malloc will copy the previous array in the new array with the new size.